# how to sort in order using Datatable for Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a table in `GridView`

```
vName   iId

Jeeva   323243
raj     4343
Abishek 3434
ramesh  4545
Manoj   7374234
viky    885
```

I want to show this table in ascending/decending order by using `DataTable`.

```
static string strcon = "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from one", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: ascending order for vName?

Comment: yep.! but not using SQL query. i want it in Datatable

Comment: Change this line. `SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from one", con);` replace your quesry with `select * from one Order By vName`. if you would like to sort after fill DataTable then you can use `DataView.Sort` from `Dt.DefaultView` or use `Select(string where,string order)` method.

Comment: please mention what is the .net framework do you use?

Comment: Framework 3.5 and VS 2008

Comment: I have asked you about .net version. becuase LINQ is not supported in .net 2.0 or lower. If you would like to use DataTable rather than DataView then you can use [LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22344439/3391751) otherwise you go with the [DataView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22344460/3391751)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
datatable.DefaultView.Sort = "yourcolumnname ASC"; 


datatable = datatable.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: @RajDeInno change it to datatable.

Answer (score 3):

Using linq:

```
var OrderedItems = dt.OrderBy(x=>x.vName).ToList();

GridView1.DataSource = OrderedItems;
```

Or order by any other column (`OrderByDescending` can be used too)